# error term of primes in arithmetic progression

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Given a positive integer $n>1$, do we have some bound  on the sequence

$$a_n=\sum_{\chi\neq 1} \sum_{p} \frac{\chi(p)}{p},$$

where $\chi$ runs over the nontrivial characters modulo $n$ and $p$ runs over all primes.

This is a real number, since

$$\sum_{\chi\neq 1} \sum_{p} \frac{\chi(p)}{p^s}=\sum_{p\equiv1(n)}\frac{\phi(n)}{p^s}-\sum_{p}\frac{1}{p^s}.$$

Here $\phi$ is Euler's function. Since by Dirichlet's theorem, ratio of the two terms on the right is $1$ when $s\rightarrow 1$. So I say this is an error term.

Comment: $\phi$ is euler's totient function, but was is $\chi$?

Comment: @unseen_rider Yes, $\phi$ is Euler's function and  $\chi$ is a character modulo $n$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel_zero